# Selenium/Cucumber not seeing step definitions after folder migration

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

Dependencies used for this:

cucumber-core-1.2.4
cucumber.html-0.2.3
cucumber-java-1.2.4
cucumber-junit-1.2.4
junit-4.11
gherkin-2.12.2 
cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3

I recently cleaned up my dependencies folder structure and think I might have misplaced something, but my problem is an instantiation issue that doesn't make sense as it seems I have my ducks in a row on the cucumber side.  Here is the stack trace:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class cucumber.feature.LoginandMeetingCreation
at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:46)
at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:32)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:299)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:121)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:40)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:770)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at cucumber.feature.LoginandMeetingCreation.<init>(LoginandMeetingCreation.java:19)
    ... 16 more
```

Here is my cucumber runner that sets up the feature files, but never executes the glue command.  My package cucumber.feature contains my step definition file LoginandMeetingCreation.java file:

```
    package cucumberInitialization;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;



@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty" , "json:target/cucumber.json"},
        features = {"src/cucumber/"},
        monochrome = true,
        glue = {"cucumber.feature"}


        )
public class cucumberRunner {

}
```

Feature file with steps:

```
Feature: Create a meeting and fill in the necessary text fields

Scenario: As a user, login and create a meeting

    Given I navigated to the site
    When I login and select an org
    Then Create a meeting
```

And finally my step definitions:

```
package cucumber.feature;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class LoginandMeetingCreation {

    WebDriver chromeDriver = null;
    WebDriver ieDriver = null;



    //open IE and Chrome browsers and go to Website
    @Given("^I navigated to the site$")
    public void navigateToWebsite() throws Throwable{
    throw new PendingException();   
    }

    //login users
    @When("^I login and select an org$")
    public void userLogin() throws Throwable{
    throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("^Create a meeting$")
    public void meetingCreation() throws Throwable{

        throw new PendingException();

    }
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: can you say me, what is in Line LoginandMeetingCreation.java:19?

Comment: all of the code you see in the last code snippet from the LoginandMeetingCreation constructor to the imports.  it's the entire .java file

Comment: Then the problem is, that you call newWebDriver(ieDriver ,2) with null. And the WebDriverWait can't be initialies without an Driver.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted a large bulk of code prior to this post to basically show the "skeleton" of what I'm dealing with, forgot to delete that line.  Edited the line.

Comment: If you look at everything at face value, it should be throwing exception errors, but instead the cucumber runner doesn't even recognize that the step definitions even exist in the LoginandMeetingCreation.java file

Comment: What is now in line 19, where the NPE occures?

Comment: It is recognizing the step definition. That is, why cucumber tries to initializes a LoginAndMeetingCreation instance. That doesn't work in cause of an NPE in Line 19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks GalexMES.

You were right, I had forgotten I had deleted a bulk amount and it dawned on me I was creating an object that cannot accept a null value.  When I had written `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(ieDriver, 5);` ieDriver was null, which causes the NPE. Once I create the ieDriver object from a non null value the expected behavior is executed.